# Using a defined jquery variable in one function inside another function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My goal is to pass the variable "platzid1" from the area click function to use it inside the btn_submit function

i have already defined the variable "platzid1" inside area click, and whenever i call it inside btn_submit, it says "undefined"

HTML:

```
<div id="22-401" id="test">
    <area id="4001" target="" alt="" title="4001" href="" coords="79,190,67,206" shape="rect"  > 
</div> 

<input name="id_input" id="id_input" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo "$id_of_input"; ?>"> </input>
```

Here is the jquery code where i try to define and use the variables:

```
var platzid1;

$(document).ready(function() {

$('area').on("click",function(){
    platzid1 = $(this).prop('id'); // storing ID of area
    var parentId1 = $(this).closest('div').prop('id');
});

$("#btn_submit").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(platzid1);
    var id = $("#id_input").val();
    var parentId = $("#Raum").val();
    var dose = $("#Dose").val();
    var mitarbeiter = $("#Mitarbeiter").val();

    if(!id || !parentId ){
        $('#message').show(15000).html("All fields are required.");
        var url = "";
    }
    else if(id != platzid1 ){
        $('#message').show(15000).html("ID does not match!");
        var url = "";
    }
```

Please ignore if some other unrelated parts of the code are missing, as i didn't copy the whole code here.

Comment: are you sure that it is defined in the area click ? try to alert it just after defining it

Comment: There are multiple errors on your page 1) remove the </input> it is not needed 2) change value="<?php echo $id_of_input ?>">

Comment: @axelaxel yes it is already defined and when i try to alert it inside area click function it works, but when i try to do it inside btn_submit function is says undefined

Comment: @jeff like already said, please ignore any mistakes or anything missing, as everything is working perfectly except on the variable-transfer part.

Comment: `platzid1` is not defined in the click handler.  It is **assigned** a value in the click handler.  If you do not perform the click of the area before the click of the button, of course it is going to be undefined.  There is no scope issue here.

Comment: Taplar is right, are you sure you've clicked on area before?

Comment: @Taplar and who said that i didn't try clicking on area? still didn't work

Comment: Did you do any alerts or logging in the area click handler to verify that it is executing?  And the logic you have given us *suggests* you did not click it first, given how scope rules work in javascript.